# Python Librosa Keras Neural Network Error: Too Many Indices For Array

Tags: python, keras, scikit-learn, neural-network, librosa

I have recently attempted to perform an experiment whereby a neural network written in the Python IDE IDLE using Keras is used to analyse the GTZAN dataset of songs. I am attempting to vary the layers in order to see if there is any impact on performance. I am basing my experiment on a particular article detailing the basis of this project:

https://medium.com/@navdeepsingh_2336/identifying-the-genre-of-a-song-with-neural-networks-851db89c42f0

On the advice of another developer on Stack Overflow, I have enlisted the assistance of the scikit-learn module.

My code is shown here:

```
import librosa
import librosa.feature
import librosa.display
import glob
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation
from keras.utils.np_utils import to_categorical

def display_mfcc(song):
    y, _ = librosa.load(song)
    mfcc = librosa.feature.mfcc(y)

    plt.figure(figsize=(10, 4))
    librosa.display.specshow(mfcc, x_axis='time', y_axis='mel')
    plt.colorbar()
    plt.title(song)
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()


def extract_features_song(f):
    y, _ = librosa.load(f)

    mfcc = librosa.feature.mfcc(y)
    mfcc /= np.amax(np.absolute(mfcc))

    return np.ndarray.flatten(mfcc)[:25000]

def generate_features_and_labels():
    all_features = []
    all_labels = []
    genres = ['blues', 'classical', 'country', 'disco', 'hiphop',
    'jazz', 'metal', 'pop', 'reggae', 'rock']

    for genre in genres:
        sound_files = glob.glob('genres/'+genre+'/*.au')
        print('Processing %d songs in %s genre...' % 
        (len(sound_files), genre))
        for f in sound_files:
            features = extract_features_song(f)
            all_features.append(features)
            all_labels.append(genre)

    label_uniq_ids, label_row_ids = np.unique(all_labels,   
    (len(sound_files), genre))
    label_row_ids = label_row_ids.astype(np.int32, copy=False)
    onehot_labels = to_categorical(label_row_ids, 
    len(label_uniq_ids))

    return np.stack(all_features), onehot_labels


features, labels = generate_features_and_labels()

print(np.shape(features))
print(np.shape(labels))

training_split = 0.8

x = features
y = labels

sss = StratifiedShuffleSplit(n_splits=1, test_size=0.20,     
random_state=37)

for train_index, test_index in sss.split(features, labels):
  x_train, x_test = features[train_index], features[test_index]
  y_train, y_test = labels[train_index], labels[test_index]

print(x_train.shape, x_test.shape, y_train.shape, y_test.shape)

train_input = train_index[:,:-10:]
train_labels = train_index[:,-10:]

test_input = test_index[:,:-10:]
test_labels = test_index[:,-10:]

print(np.shape(train_input))
print(np.shape(train_labels))

model = Sequential([
    Dense(100, input_dim=np.shape(train_input)[1]),
    Activation('relu'),
    Dense(10),
    Activation('softmax'),
    ])


model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
print(model.summary())

model.fit(train_input, train_labels, epochs=10, batch_size=32,
          validation_split=0.2) 
loss, acc = model.evaluate(test_input, test_labels, batch_size=32)

print('Done!')
print('Loss: %.4f, accuracy: %.4f' % (loss, acc))
```

As I ran the program, Python began to print the expected response:

```
Processing 100 songs in blues genre...
Processing 100 songs in classical genre...
Processing 100 songs in country genre...
Processing 100 songs in disco genre...
Processing 100 songs in hiphop genre...
Processing 100 songs in jazz genre...
Processing 100 songs in metal genre...
Processing 100 songs in pop genre...
Processing 100 songs in reggae genre...
Processing 100 songs in rock genre...
(1000, 25000)
(1000, 10)
(800, 25000) (200, 25000) (800, 10) (200, 10)
```

But this was interrupted by an error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/surengrigorian/Documents/Stage1.py", line 74, in <module>
    train_input = train_index[:,:-10:]
IndexError: too many indices for array
```

Thank you for any assistance concerning this issue.

Answer (score 0):

That's because `train_index` and `test_index` are 1-D arrays which contain the index of samples to be used in train and test resp. They themselves are not the data. You trying to access the second axis (by doing `[:,:-10:]`) on a 1-D array is the problem.

Please specify what do you want to do in the line:

```
train_input = train_index[:,:-10:]
```

Comment: I am attempting to feed the information into the arrays. However, I would like to know what to do in order to prevent this error by only accessing the relevant information in the array. Thank you for your assistance.